# Silent bulk printing PDF in ASP.Net MVC 4 to default printer

Tags: asp.net-mvc

We need to implement bulk printing in asp.net mvc 4; we have tried with Process.Start for the same; but it works in development environment

When we publish the same on IIS it does not work; can you please let us know solution for the same

Thanks in advance

Comment: Define "it does not work."  Is there an error?  Does the server not have a printer?  Are you trying to print to the *client* (which isn't going to work for very obvious reasons)?

Comment: There is no error thrown; also server has default printer configured; this works in development environment but not working when we host in IIS

Comment: What is the output of the process being started?  I don't think .NET is going to inherently capture any exception from an external process, so you'll need to check its output manually.  Maybe the application's user context doesn't have permission to invoke the process?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback; we have already set required permissions for application pool